# Invertir cadenas en C++

Tags: c++, string

estoy aprendiendo a usar la función de invertir cadenas en C++, pero al realizar mi primer programa, me marca error.

```
/* Invertir una cadena*/
 #include <iostream>
 #include <conio.h>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

char cadena[]= "Silvana";

strrev(cadena);

cout<<cadena<<endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `string.h` es una librería propia de `C`. Si estás codificando en `C++` debes usar `cstring.h`

Comment: @Londo Tendría que ser solo `cstring`, sin el `.h` al final.

Comment: Lo mejor sería usar funcionalidad de STL. Por ejemplo la clase [`string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) de `string` y la función [`reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) de `algorithm`. Después de todo `strrev` es una función que está haciendo el trabajo por ti. No habrá diferencia en hacer `reverse(cadena.begin(), cadena.end())`.

Comment: utiliza la librería `cstring` y la función `reverse` para invertir la cadena.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que estás en C++, usa C++. Para manejar cadenas, C++ pone a tu disposición la clase `std::string`:

std::string palabra = "abcdef";

Una vez tienes la palabra en un `string`, para invertir la palabra puedes usar `std::reverse`

```
std::string inversa = palabra;
std::reverse(inversa.begin(), inversa.end());
```

O también puedes invertir la cadena usando el constructor correspondiente de `std::string`:

```
std::string inversa(palabra.rbegin(), palabra.rend());
```

Si no quieres dar el paso a `std::string`, aún puedes seguir usando `std::reverse`. Esta función espera recibir dos punteros (inicio y fin) o dos iteradores, por lo que puede ser usada por un array de C:

```
char palabra[] = "abcdef";
std::reverse(std::begin(palabra), std::end(palabra));
```

Ojo, si ya no fuese un array sino un puntero la cosa cambiaría, ya que no podrías usar `std::begin` y `std::end`, pues estas funciones no pueden trabajar con punteros. En este caso tendrías que calcular previamente la posición del fin del string:

```
char * palabra = new char[100];
strcpy(palabra, "abcdef");

char * end = palabra + strlen(palabra);
std::reverse(palabra, end);
```